# How to create a .NET Core AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Script

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After several days digging the web and AWS documentation I could not find a valid way to create a deployment script for a .NET Core application for AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm using a git repository to store the application and AWS CodePipeline to retrieve the code and build the app, that work fine.

My major issue is when Code Deploy try to install the app on the EBS EC2 instance.

All the AWS info only mention use the Microsoft Visual Studio deploy to AWS feature, but that isn't my case.

Any help could be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AWS CodeDeploy is a service that automates code deployments to currently running EC2 instances. I don't believe you can use it to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk. Have you considered using CodeStar? CodeStar can set up the EC2 instance for you the way elastic beanstalk does and set up your entire pipeline and supports .NET Core 1.0. If you want it to support .NET Core 2.0 you can attach an appspec and a build spec yaml file to instruct CodeBuild to install .net core 2.0 and the packages required so that the instance can run .NET Core 2.0 applications.  The files would like similar to these in Github in one of our sample projects https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-net-chatbot/tree/master/Linux%20Deployment